# Kali GNU/LInux Rolling

Tags: debian, kali-linux, root

I installed Kali on my PC and rebooted my PC. I then created the password so now it wants a login and a password when I type in root and the password it says login incorrect.

I can't go back to normal Windows

Answer (score 0):

In kali 2.0 the root default account was removed. But you can enable it. First login as user "kali" with password "kali". Then open terminal and run "sudo passwd root" and set a password for root account and then reboot. Now you can login as root from your set password.